# Can I solve the linear partial differential equation like an ordinary differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I have a linear partial differential equation with respect to $T(x,t)$:

$$\frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2}-f(t)\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}=0,$$

which is subjected to two boundary conditions:

$T(h_1, t)=T_0(t)$, and $T(h_2, t)=T_{\infty}=const$,
where $f(t)$ is an unknown function of $t$.

My question is can one regards it as a linear ordinary differential equation (DE) with constant coefficients. Thus, its characteristic equation can be

$$r^2-f(t)r=0.$$

So the two characteristic roots are $r_1=0, r_2=f(t)$, and the general solution to the homogeneous DE might be written as

$$T(x,t)=A \sinh [f(t)x]+B \cosh (0 x)=A \sinh [f(t)x]+B.$$

Thank you for your advice!

Comment: A way to find out is to simply try it. The Ansatz is not that difficult.